# access protected variable in derived class c++

Tags: c++, class, protected, derived

I have a mother class and a derived daughter class. I am trying to access the protected variable 'familystuff' in the derived class. Both ways that I am trying to access it aren't working. When I compile and run it, I get the following output:

5 3 1

1

Familie 32768

FOO 32767

```
class Mother
 {
 private:
        int motherstuff;
 protected:
         int familystuff;
 public:
         int everyonesstuff;
         void SetStuff(int a, int b, int c){
            motherstuff = a;
            familystuff = b;
            everyonesstuff = c;
         }
         void Show(){
            cout << motherstuff << " " << familystuff << " " <<everyonesstuff << endl;
        }
};

class Daughter : public Mother
{
public:
    Daughter()
    {
            a = familystuff + 1;
    }
    void Show(){
            cout << "Familie " << a << endl;
    }
    int foo() { return familystuff;}
    private:
        int a;
 };

 int main(){

    Mother myMum;
    myMum.SetStuff(5,3,1);
    myMum.Show();
    cout << myMum.everyonesstuff << endl;

    Daughter myDaughter;
    myDaughter.Show();
    cout << "FOO " << myDaughter.foo() << endl;
}
```

Comment: `myDaughter` is an entirely different object, it doesn't magically share memory with `myMum`

Comment: You don't give `myDaughter` any values so it contains random mush.

Comment: So think for a second -- how would you declare 2 or 3 Mother objects, and then tie them to a Daughter?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: 3 Mothers for a Daughter?

Comment: That's my point.  I'm trying to explain to the OP that their example is nonsensical if they tried to expand it to merely create 2 Mothers / Daughters.

Comment: You'll just confuse her/him. If you want to explain, explain...

Comment: Let the OP decide what is confusing.  I will give him / her the benefit of the doubt that they can grasp the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a clear concept in object oriented programming. When you create two objects, then they are completely different from each other. They do not interact with each other until they are forced.So,

- `myMum` and `myDaughter` are seperate objects and they do not share the values of their variables.
- The last two outputs are basically garbage values. You have not initialized myDaughter's `familystuff`

So, if you want to access protected members from derived class, you need to write the following :

```
int main()
{
    Daughter myDaughter(5,3,1);
    myDaughter.Show();
    cout << "FOO " << myDaughter.foo() << endl;
 }
```

Change the Daughter's constructor to the following :

```
Daughter(int x,int y,int z)
    {
            SetStuff(x,y,z);
            a = familystuff + 1;
    }
```

You will get the desired output!!

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong here:

1. `myDaughter` and `myMum` are **different objects**. You imply some kind of relationship between them, but there is none.
2. Your code has **undefined behaviour**, because your `Daughter` constructor uses the uninitialised member variable `familystuff` in an addition operation.
3. You should **initialise** your data members like this:

   `Mother::Mother() : motherstuff(0), familystuff(0), everyonesstuff(0) {}`

   `Daughter::Daugher() : a(familystuff + 1) {}`